# Config section not loading

Tags: c#, web-config

I've declaration of my config section in web.config (in `configSection` element):

```
<section name="gmailEmail" type="MyApp.Communication.Sections.GmailSection" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

And usage:

```
<gmailEmail>
  <from emailAddress="pat.wasiewicz@gmail.com" name="MyApp"></from>
  <server password="mysuperpass">
</gmailEmail>
```

My config model:

```
public class GmailSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("server")]
    public ServerElement Server { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("from")]
    public FromElement From { get; set; }
}

public class ServerElement : ConfigurationElement
{


    [ConfigurationProperty("host", DefaultValue = "smtp.gmail.com", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("port", DefaultValue = 587, IsRequired = false)]
    public int Port { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("ssl", DefaultValue = true, IsRequired = false)]
    public bool Ssl { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("password", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class FromElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("emailAddress", IsRequired = true)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortanely, there is a problem:

```
var configSection = (GmailSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("gmailEmail");
```

`configSection.Server`  is `null` and `configSection.From` is `null`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type name for the configuration section is missing the assembly name

```
<section name="gmailEmail" type="MyApp.Communication.Sections.GmailSection, MyApp" allowLocation=.....
```

The server/password element is missing the close tag ( /> )

```
<server password="mysuperpass" />
```

But I think these are typos.

You should change all your { get; set; } property implementations to call the base class' indexer with the same key. I have implemented the GmailSection class, and you can modify the ServerElement and FormElement classes the same way.

```
public class GmailSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("server")]
    public ServerElement Server
    {
        get
        {
            return (ServerElement)this["server"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["server"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("from")]
    public FromElement From
    {
        get
        {
            return (FromElement)this["from"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["from"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So.. `Server` and `From` properties has instances... but values (password, name, emailAddress) are not read from config (there is null everywhere).

Comment: Ok, making all properties to work like `this[...]` (even for primitive types) made it works. Strange, every tutorial shows that value should be injected without that...

Comment: Actually in my reproduction of the error, the runtime complained about the getter methods returning null. In the error message, it also said that I should call base["server"].